# Append text to text area with jquery issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

Im trying to make some buttons append text to a textarea with jquery, and I have it working, but only if I dont type anything into the textarea itself.

Code:

```
<textarea name="comments" id="comments" rows="20" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; width: 968px;"></textarea>
<div>
  <button>+petname</button>
  <button>+lastvisit</button>
  <button>+nextvisit</button>
</div>
<script>
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  var text = $( this ).text();
  $('#comments').append(text); 
});
</script>
```

This code is working, but the minute I type something else into that text area, the buttons no longer work??? WHY!!?? I just cant figure it out.
Much thanks.
Jason

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of doing `append` set `val` using its function argument syntax, do this way:

```
$('#comments').val(function(_, val){
    return val + text; 
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/833Lf/)**

Answer (score 3):

change

```
$('#comments').append(text);
```

to

```
$('#comments').val( $('#comments').val() + " " + text );
```