# Jquery pass input value to textarea

Tags: jquery, html

Im trying to pass the textbox value to textarea but I cant come up with the idea how to add new value to the existing in the textarea.

```
$('#firstnametxt').change(function () {
                $('#rev').val($('#firstnametxt').val());
            });

            $('#lastnametxt').change(function () {
                $('#rev').val($('#lastnametxt').val());
            });
```

rev is textarea id.

I would like to seperate entries into new row as well. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Append text to text area with jquery issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20602241/append-text-to-text-area-with-jquery-issue)

Comment: Thanks @MikeMcCaughan and Muhammad Omer Aslam looks like I solved this one.

Comment: that sounds good.

Answer (score 1):

The `onchange` is only triggered when focus out of the input. Try `onkeypress` instead.

```
$('#firstnametxt').on('keypress',function() {
  $('#rev').val($(this).val());
});

$('#lastnametxt').on('keypress',function() {
  $('#rev').val($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand well you looking for

```js
function setValues(){
  $('#rev').val(
    $('#firstnametxt').val() + "\n" + $('#lastnametxt').val()
  );
}

$('#firstnametxt').change(setValues);
$('#lastnametxt').change(setValues);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="firstnametxt" name="firstnametxt" type="text"><br>
<input id="lastnametxt" name="lastnametxt" type="text"><br>
<textarea id="rev" name="rev"></textarea>
```